# regex - min and max character length, weird error when copy and pasting text

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I use asp.net and c#.

I have a weird problems with Regular Expression for a text box. As you can see from my snippet, I'm using RegularExpressionValidator it should work from the Client and Server side.

I'm testing the TextBox and I have notice when I copy and past some text from some web pages in the TextBox the RegularExpressionValidator seems does not work properly (the result seems an empty input) (if instead I type some text is working fine).

I'm concerning if my RegEx is correct "`^([\s\S]){4,128}$"` I need to check if the input is within length of minim 4 and max 128 characters long.

- Any idea what could be the problem?
- How can I debug the Js

Thanks

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxRegularExpressionValidatorTitleMaxLengthDisplayer"
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxTitleInputer" ErrorMessage="Title is too short or to long. Minimum 4 and Maximum 128 are allowed."
                            ValidationExpression="^([\s\S]){4,128}$">* Too short or too long</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Why don't you use: `^.{4,128}$`?

Comment: I need include in the content even Special Character and Underscore

Comment: @GibboK Well your regex is not the problem. You need to control that the validation check occurs after the text is pasted or something among these lines. Check when you fire your event.

Comment: Thanks FailedDev for your advice.

Comment: @GibboK Time for some debugging then :)

Comment: Thanks FailedDev I found out the problem, I use EF for my Data Model. So the corresponding field was set to 64 length and my regex was on 128 this was the problem as fact the regex was fine. Thanks for your hi :-) up-voted your comment

Answer (score 1):

It might be a wild guess but give it a shot. Assuming your regex is correct:

1. Add validation group to the Regex Validator and the control from which validation is called.

like

```
<asp:TextBox  id="uxTitleInputer" runat="server">
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxRegularExpressionValidatorTitleMaxLengthDisplayer"
                            runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxTitleInputer" ErrorMessage="Title is too short or to long. Minimum 4 and Maximum 128 are allowed."
                            ValidationExpression="^([\s\S]){4,128}$"

ValidationGroup="valGrp"
>* Too short or too long</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


<asp:Button Id="btnChk" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valGrp"/>

<asp:Validationsummary id.... ShowMessageBox="true"  ValidationGroup="valGrp"/>
```

Comment: thanks Amit, but the problem was smt else, but I will consider your script many thanks